# identify SMT component: stripe 36 27

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image: There are 5 instances of the component in the photo.]

I need help identifying a surface mount component:

1. SMT package, black color, 2-terminal, gullwing longitudinal direction,  LxWxH = 5x2.5x2 mm
2. markings are a stripe, then 36 on new line, then 27 on new line (another example is marked stripe newline 34 newline 25).

My guess is some sort of diode, but searching has yielded no result so far. Any ideas? I can't even find a known package type that fits this description. Package is bigger than an SOD323, for example.

There are 5 instances of the component in the photo.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a photo of it and surrounding circuitry.

Comment: Photo added: 2 instances near middle west side, 1 near north side, 2 near south-east corner.

Comment: The picture is way too small to be helpful. At the very least, the markings should be visible.

Comment: The markings are hidden by the conformal coating. They will not show on any photo due to light reflection.  Please go by the markings I spelled out above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to say for sure with the current low resolution photo, but it could be a [ROHM RB060L-40](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2101181805_ROHM-Semicon-RB060L-40TE25_C919457.pdf) Schottky diode. SMA roughly matches with the given size and the similar diode marked "34" could be a [RB160L-40](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810131711_ROHM-Semicon-RB160L-40TE25_C81484.pdf) from the same series.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The marking style (layout,color, font) is VERY similar. and the package size LxWxH = 4.5 x 2.6 x 2.0 is also very close to what I was able to measure. The only thing missing is gull-wing, but I'll look for a gull-wing version to confirm. Thanks much for this pointer. I see the package pictured is called DO-214AC (SMA), great to know also.

Comment: UPDATE: My component might not be gull-wing after all, it may indeed be J-lead like the Rohm above. The visual similarity to a gull-wing could just be an illusion caused by the way the solder slopes away from the terminal.